# hover: how to trigger UI effect once?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-hover

How to trigger jQuery-UI effect only once on mouseenter?

http://jsfiddle.net/MG4JZ/

```
$('#menu a').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).css({
        'background-color': 'white',
        'color': 'black',
    }).effect('slide'); // EFFECT
  }, function() {
    $(this).css({
        'background': 'none',
        'color': 'white',
    });
});
```

It keeps running forever while mouse is over.

Comment: Why not use [`.mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) if you want something to happen on mouse enter. Or do you want it to only ever happen once?

Comment: hover is a shortcut to mouseenter and mouseleave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the slide effect being used because the `<a>` slides in from the left and gets a second `.hover()` event. I use the fact that the element gains `position:relative` from jQueryUI when it is animating to determine whether to add the effect or not.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wu8QJ/)

Adding the CSS

```
#menu a:hover {
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
}​
```

and simply using [`.mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)

```
$('#menu a').mouseenter(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.css('position') === 'relative') return;
    $(this).effect('slide'); // EFFECT
});​
```

seems to solve it for me.

**Edit:** So thanks to Matthew in the comments for pointing out that when hovering on the far right, the event still fires multiple times. So here is an updated answer. It uses the newer jQuery [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) syntax but you could still use the older methods to achieve the same result. It now uses two events, one on the anchors to add the *hover* style and effect but **only** if when entering the anchor, the element does not already have the class. I also remove the hover class from all other anchors when hovering an anchor. The second event covers the removal of the hover class when exiting the whole menu. Without this second event the last anchor hovered when moving away from the menu is left with the `.hover` class.

[**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wu8QJ/1/)

JavaScript

```
var $anchors = $('#menu a');

$('#menu').on('mouseenter', 'a', function() {
    $anchors.not(this).removeClass('hover');

    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('hover')) return;
    $this.addClass('hover').effect('slide'); // EFFECT
});

$('#menu').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $anchors.removeClass('hover');
});​
```

CSS

```
#menu {
    background-color: black;
}

#menu a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
}

#menu a.hover {
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
}​
```

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still suffers from the same problem where the div loses the mouseenter when you are hovering more than 100px or so from the left. :(

Comment: How wide is the menu going to be ;-) But yeah, I was hovering close-ish to the text so didn't spot that - thanks!

Comment: Yes it was, as @MatthewBlancarte has already pointed out. I have updated my answer with a different approach which seems to work better for me

Answer (score 0):

Please try this http://jsfiddle.net/MG4JZ/6/

```
$("#menu a").mouseenter(function(){
   $(this).css({
      'background-color': 'white',
      'color': 'black',
    }).stop(true,true).effect('slide');
}).mouseleave(function(){
   $(this).css({
    'background': 'none',
    'color': 'white',
   });
});
```

or

```
$("#menu a").hover(function(){
   $(this).css({
      'background-color': 'white',
      'color': 'black',
    }).stop(true,true).effect('slide');
},function(){
   $(this).css({
    'background': 'none',
    'color': 'white',
   });
});
```

​
​

Comment: yes but you are getting issue on that hover na?.... try this http://jsfiddle.net/MG4JZ/6/ it works fine

Comment: The problem is persisting even though you changed from hover to mouseenter and mouseleave. You can see it in your own demo...

Comment: Hover your mouse 100 pixels to the right of links. You'll see the problem. :)